Why secp521r1 curve EC point Hex representation starting with 0x048185 instead of 0x0485?
For prime256v1/secp256r1 or secp256k1 I see the EC point value in HEX as per SEC standard starts with 0x0441, indicating it is in uncompressed format and there are 4116 or 6510 bytes in total - 32 bytes for x co-ordinate, 32 bytes for y co-ordinate, and 1 byte to mention 0x04 (uncompressed format). Here is one example of EC point value which I see after generating prime256v1 EC key inside HSM:
0x0441 04 710b202684071917531de9f26889b3c4696ca7b6a0ccc143eadc496cc292191a523253aeb3274a8ef20c6f4644c1d57bf4e7fb5c723a9dc400e5f998562b997b

Similarly, for secp384r1 curve, following same calculation we have (384 / 8) * 2 + 1 = 97 bytes, which is 61 in base 16 and hence we have EC point Hex value starting with 0x0461. All good so far.
But, if we follow same calculation for secp521r1 curve, 521 bits / 8 ~ 66 bytes. Hence, 66 bytes x co-ordinate + 66 bytes y co-ordinate + 1 byte to represent compression = 133 total bytes in decimal - which is 85 in Hex format. So the Hex representation of EC point should start with 0x0485. Then, why secp521r1 curve EC point HEX representation starting with 0x048185 instead of 0x0485? Here is one example EC point value which I got after generating secp521r1 EC key inside a HSM (adding space for better readability):
0x048185 04 01354ffc3ce6133de742e5370391d81bc3a81b4fcba467f2da8884d058e08086dc6fc7e13f1c46fa89324457a2adbac9b10a626e5ac4f47be3f8a087a7506a1fc5f7012d7228479f8c08b71cbc8c3c36b9eca119c088a0cf603e60488d2f4fdce15d2bff5cc65d2bd09231f8e76ca7f5327edcdbd5a013fd8f80819702127ea20c6e97b2


Step 3.3. of section 2.3.3. Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Cerversion says: Output $M = 04_{16}||X||Y$. what appears to be a length octet is just coincidence.

@DannyNiu No, this is just about the DER encoding of an OCTET STRING that the HSM uses.

The 0x0441 before the uncompressed points of secp256r1 and secp256k1 consists of two bytes:

0x04 is the ASN.1/DER encoded tag of an OCTET STRING
0x41 is the ASN.1/DER encoded length of 65 bytes
the rest, starting with 0x04, is the uncompressed point

This is what you also concluded, as $1 + 2 \times \lceil{256 / 8} \rceil = 1 + 2 \times 32 = 65$ bytes.
Obviously the same goes for secp521r1 which need to encode 133 bytes, as you correctly concluded: $1 + 2 \times \lceil{521 / 8} \rceil = 1 + 2 \times 66 = 133$ bytes.
However, the length encoding of ASN.1 changes once the value 0x80 / 128 is reached. It then changes to 0x80 + the amount of bytes to encode an unsigned big endian integer, followed by the most efficient encoding (i.e. not zero padded) integer.
So what you get is 0x048185 which means:

0x04 the octet string
0x8185 the length encoding: 0x81 which means 1 byte length encoding followed by 0x85 which is 133 in hexadecimals.
the rest, starting with 0x04 is the uncompressed point

The uncompressed point consists of 0x04 followed by the concatenation of the encoding of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates as statically sized, unsigned, big integer values.
For more information see the A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER by Burton S. Kaliski Jr. or look into ITU-T X.680 or ISO/IEC 8824-1 for ASN.1 and ITU-T X.690 or ISO/IEC 8825-1 for BER / DER.
It is also possible to decode DER in tools such as CyberChef, the online ASN.1 JavaScript decoder which accepts hex or base 64, or of course openssl asn1parse.
You may need to strip off the ASN.1 tag and length bytes as most software won't expect the OCTET STRING encoding.

Sheesh, that's a long answer to explain 0x8185, I might as well change my name to fgrieu ;)

PKCS11, which many HSMs obey, requires DER of EC_POINT for own key and allows but does not require it for peer pubkey/point in ECDH (but for ECDSA signature uses bare r||s not DER)

@dave_thompson_085 That's just weird, but I stand corrected (again). You've got a great memory for such detail.
